# Panasonic GH3/ Exfat Issues: file system is larger than underlying device

Tags: filesystem, camera, exfat

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and have a Panasonic GH3 DSLR that I would like to connect to my computer. At first I was giving me an issue about not read Exfat file system. Googled and found this page(https://askubuntu.com/questions/66747...-in-cardreader) I tried both and it didn't work. I couldn't do the first one as chmod 777 gave me a operation not permitted. It has changed the error to:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/chris/1548-F934: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,io charset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/chris/1548-F934"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.1.0`
stderr: `ERROR: file system is larger than underlying device: 64071139328 64071138816.`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.